# delete image from gallery - android

Tags: android

I'm making an app that captures image from camera and uploades it to firebase. After uploading the image to firebase, I want to remove the image from the Camera folder of gallery and another folder named Pictures which is created automatically after an image is captured. I have tried multiple solutions from SO, but none worked. I have tried to remove image from uri using file.delete() and from path, but the image is still there in the above mentioned folders. I'm using API 21, and I have read on SO somewhere that we cannot access sd card files by file.delete(), so what could be a solution? Please suggest something that works on every device >= API 19. Also, please suggest a way that works no matter where the image is being saved, i.e. whether it is external or internal memory, because I don't know about the storage settings a user would have on his phone.

I am providing some code snippets here, please let me know if anything else is needed.

I'm creating intent object like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I'm doing the uploading work here:

```
       @Override
         protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!= null){
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.waitwhilepicisuploaded);
            mediaPlayer.start();

            final Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            //the tap to open camera button disappears
            tapCameraBtn.setVisibility(Button.GONE);

            //setting the color of progress bar to white
            progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN );

            //and now we make the progress bar visible instead of the button
            progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

            mCount = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber().toString()).child("count");

            uploadPhoto(mCount, photo);
        }

    }

    public void uploadPhoto(DatabaseReference mCount, Bitmap photo){

        final Uri uri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);


        final String userPhoneNumber = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
        uniquefilename = userPhoneNumber.toString();

        mCount.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                photoCounter = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);

                //uploading image captured to firebase
                uploadPhotoToFirebase(uri, userPhoneNumber, uniquefilename, photoCounter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("The read failed: ", "FAILED");
            }
        });

    }

    public void uploadPhotoToFirebase(Uri uri, final String userPhoneNumber, String uniquefilename, int photoCounter){

        final StorageReference filepath = storageReference.child("/" + uniquefilename + "/photos/" + "photo_" + photoCounter);

        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();

                filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        deleteFile(uri);
                        uploadPhotoToKairos(uri,userPhoneNumber);


                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle any errors
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URI not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                Toast.makeText(AddContactActivity.this, "Uploading finished!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(AddContactActivity.this, RecordAudioActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

  deleteFile(Uri uri){

        File fdelete = new File(uri.getPath());
        if (fdelete.exists()) {
           if (fdelete.delete()) {
                Log.d("file deleted" , uri.getPath());
           } else {
                Log.d("file not Deleted " , uri.getPath());
           }
        }
  }



    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);

        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

Also, the following permissions are there in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have removed all the unwanted code that I tried from various answers from SO, and this is the original code.

Comment: @ Yuva K you have not mentioned code to delete the image file?

Comment: @userI I have added the code. I tried a lot of methods but this was the one that I tried most of the times with some changes but the images were still there in the gallery. One more thing, `fdelete.exists()` always returns `false`, I dont understand that as well.

Comment: firstly check deleteFile() function gets called or not

Answer (score 1):

Just create your own file for capturing in any of the directory and save that file_path(String) anywhere.

then pass that file to intent like this

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            //for nougat and above using file provider..
    takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "provider path(like package)", file));
        } else {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
        }
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,
                CAMERA_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

get the URI or file from file_path and get the image or bitmap whatever you need from file path.
delete the file by file path.

please check this for file provider

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider